# T or F: If a mahine using paged virutal memory has a 24-bit logical address and a 32-bit physical address, a page fault will never occur

Tags: memory, operating-system, virtual, paging

I'm working on a practice final exam and I can't seem to figure out the answer to this question.

My understanding is that every initial page being brought in counts as a page fault, so even without the address lengths, this question should be false, correct? If we forget about this for a second, is the answer true? My thought behind this is that since the logical address only has 24 bits while the physical address has 32 bits, there would never be a case where the page has to be in a frame that is already occupied. Is more information required (such as page size) for this realm of reasoning?

Answer (score 1):

> every initial page being brought in counts as a page fault

Just as a note, this is true only if you create the process (populate the PCB, *process control block*) but you don't actually assign *any* frame. The first (and some of the other) reference (basically, the first istruction) will generate a page fault.

This is why you (*you* as the OS) have to assign a sufficent number of frame to avoid early page fault (and, with a pinch of luck and a good pager, even later in the execution of the process).

Back at your question: the answer is **false** (*depends* is more correct).

The reason is simple: if you don't know the size of the memory, you can't actually know how many frame do you have at hand. So the address size is totally useless in this specific context.